# JavaScript Type Error 'childnodes' undefined

Tags: javascript, html, function, exception, typeerror

Need to Dynamically Add/Remove rows in HTML table using JavaScript getting a type error.

Type Error: cannot read property 'childNodes' of undefined?

Catches this exception in run time during deleteRow function execution.

On pressing Add Row, a dynamic row will be created and added in the table. And on selecting the checkbox and pressing Delete Row, the row will be removed.

Following is the source.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
var b = new Array();
var entryListCounter = 0;
var counter = 0;

function insertEntry(f) {

var test = 0;

    //local array collects input values
    var a = new Array();

    a[0] = f.ticker.value;
    a[1] = f.cusip.value;
    a[2] = f.quantity.value;

    //store local array in entry list array
    b[entryListCounter] = a;

    entryListCounter++;


    if (a[0] == "" && a[1] == "" || a[2] == "") {
        console.log("val not filled");
    } 
    else if(a[0].length > 0 && a[1].length > 0){
        console.log("only fill one");
    }
    else {
        var table = document.getElementById("manualEntryInputTable");
        var row = table.insertRow(table.rows.length);

        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var t1 = document.createElement("input");
        t1.id = "t" + counter;
        cell1.appendChild(t1);

        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        var t2 = document.createElement("input");
        t2.id = "c" + counter;
        cell2.appendChild(t2);

        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
        var t3 = document.createElement("input");
        t3.id = "q" + counter;
        t3.style = "text-align:right";
        cell3.appendChild(t3);

        var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
        var t4 = document.createElement("input");
        t4.type = "checkbox";
        t4.name = "chkbox";
        cell4.appendChild(t4);

        f.quantity.value = "";
        f.cusip.value = "";
        f.ticker.value = "";
    }
}

        function deleteRow(e) {
            try {
            var table = document.getElementById("manualEntryInputTable");
            var rowCount = table.rows.length;

            for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
                var row = table.rows[i];
                var chkbox = row.cells[3].childNodes[0];
                if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
                    if(rowCount <= 1) {
                        alert("Cannot delete all the rows.");
                        break;
                    }
                    table.deleteRow(i);
                    rowCount--;
                    i--;
                }


            }
            }catch(e) {
                alert(e);
            }
        }




</script>

</head>

<body>
<form>
        <table id="manualEntryInputTable">
            <tr>
                <td><b>T</b></td>
                <td><b>C</b></td>
                <td><b>Q</b></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="label"><input size="" type="text" name="ticker"
                    value="" ></td>
                <td class="label"><input size="" type="text" name="cusip"
                    value=""></td>
                <td class="label"><input size="" type="text" name="quantity"
                     style="text-align: right;" value="">
                </td>
                <td><input type="button" onClick="insertEntry(this.form)" value="Add"/>
                </td>
                <td><input type="button" onClick="deleteRow(this.form)" value="Delete"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
</form> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There's only three cells in `table.rows[0]`. You might want to start the loop from `1` instead of `0`?

Comment: i cant believe i missed that :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at the conditional checking for `null`, I would rewrite it like this:

```
var chkbox = row.cells[3].childNodes.length ? row.cells[3].childNodes[0] : null;
```

That should avoid the error being thrown, but might not get the row deleted if the cell with index 3 doesn't exist. Consider checking the value of the right cell index `row.cells[YOUR_CELL_INDEX_HERE].childNodes[0]`

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what you are trying to do, but the reason for exception is that you are trying to access the element which doesn't exists.

This line is giving the error `row.cells[3].childNodes[0]` since you do not have `row.cell[3]` property. The `row.Cells` has length 3 but since the index starts from `0`, you can refer to the last element using `row.cells[2]` You get undefined and hence  `row.cells[3].childNodes[0]` method doesn't work.

change it to `row.cells[2].childNodes[0]`

```html
<html>
<head>
<script>
var b = new Array();
var entryListCounter = 0;
var counter = 0;

function insertEntry(f) {

var test = 0;

    //local array collects input values
    var a = new Array();

    a[0] = f.ticker.value;
    a[1] = f.cusip.value;
    a[2] = f.quantity.value;

    //store local array in entry list array
    b[entryListCounter] = a;

    entryListCounter++;


    if (a[0] == "" && a[1] == "" || a[2] == "") {
        console.log("val not filled");
    } 
    else if(a[0].length > 0 && a[1].length > 0){
        console.log("only fill one");
    }
    else {
        var table = document.getElementById("manualEntryInputTable");
        var row = table.insertRow(table.rows.length);

        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var t1 = document.createElement("input");
        t1.id = "t" + counter;
        cell1.appendChild(t1);

        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        var t2 = document.createElement("input");
        t2.id = "c" + counter;
        cell2.appendChild(t2);

        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
        var t3 = document.createElement("input");
        t3.id = "q" + counter;
        t3.style = "text-align:right";
        cell3.appendChild(t3);

        var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
        var t4 = document.createElement("input");
        t4.type = "checkbox";
        t4.name = "chkbox";
        cell4.appendChild(t4);

        f.quantity.value = "";
        f.cusip.value = "";
        f.ticker.value = "";
    }
}

        function deleteRow(e) {
            try {
            var table = document.getElementById("manualEntryInputTable");
            var rowCount = table.rows.length;

            for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
                var row = table.rows[i];
                var chkbox = row.cells[2].childNodes[0];
                if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
                    if(rowCount <= 1) {
                        alert("Cannot delete all the rows.");
                        break;
                    }
                    table.deleteRow(i);
                    rowCount--;
                    i--;
                }


            }
            }catch(e) {
                alert(e);
            }
        }




</script>

</head>

<body>
<form>
        <table id="manualEntryInputTable">
            <tr>
                <td><b>T</b></td>
                <td><b>C</b></td>
                <td><b>Q</b></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="label"><input size="" type="text" name="ticker"
                    value="" ></td>
                <td class="label"><input size="" type="text" name="cusip"
                    value=""></td>
                <td class="label"><input size="" type="text" name="quantity"
                     style="text-align: right;" value="">
                </td>
                <td><input type="button" onClick="insertEntry(this.form)" value="Add"/>
                </td>
                <td><input type="button" onClick="deleteRow(this.form)" value="Delete"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
</form> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That should avoid the exception. Are you still getting the same error ?

Comment: I pasted the code in snippet, i do not see the error.