# JavaScript TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, delete-row, typeerror

## Preface:

I have an HTML table where user fills in Name and URL of social networks where they have account. Each row has a checkbox. With the help of jQuery and JavaScript, on pressing Add Row button, a row is dynamically added to the table and on pressing delete row button those rows are deleted for which checkbox is checked.

## Objective:

When selected rows are deleted, I want to assign `id` to input elements and checkboxes of every remaining row in serial manner, so that the rows are always serially sound.

## Problem:

I am not able to find what makes it throw error, as `childNodes[]` do not seem to lead to unavailable element. Please help!

## Snippet:

```js
    // variable to keep track of rows(records)
    var social_recs_num = 1;
    $(document).ready(function () {
    
      $("#social_add_rec").click(function () {
    
        social_recs_num++;
        var markup = "<tr> <th scope=\"row\"> <div class=\"form-group\"> <div class=\"form-check\"> <input type=\"checkbox\" class=\"form-check-input\" id=\"social_rec" + social_recs_num + "\" name=\"social_rec\"> <label class=\"form-check-label\" for=\"social_rec" + social_recs_num + "\"> " + social_recs_num + "</label> </div></div></th> <td> <div class=\"form-group shadow-sm\"> <label for=\"name_social" + social_recs_num + "\">Select or Type</label> <input type=\"text\" list=\"name_social" + social_recs_num + "\" class=\"form-control\" placeholder=\"Name\"> <datalist id=\"name_social" + social_recs_num + "\"> <option value=\"Wikipedia\">Wikipedia</option> <option value=\"Youtube\">Youtube</option> <option value=\"Facebook\">Facebook</option> <option value=\"Twitter\">Twitter</option> <option value=\"Pinterest\">Pinterest</option> </datalist> </div></td><td> <div class=\"form-group shadow-sm\"> <textarea class=\"form-control\" id=\"url_social" + social_recs_num + "\" cols=\"30\" rows=\"1\" placeholder=\"URL\"></textarea> </div></td></tr>"; //in case of id we need to do it like: "min_sysreq" +social_recs_num...as social_recs_num has been incremented priorly it will be the row number of row to be added
    
        $("table tbody").append(markup);
    
      });
    
      // Find and remove selected table rows...only condition is that there must be present attribute name='sysreq_rec' in input element for checkbox of every row
    
      $("#social_delete_rec").click(function () {
    
        $("table tbody").find('input[name="social_rec"]').each(function () {
    
          if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            social_recs_num = social_recs_num - $(this).length;
            $(this).parents("tr").remove();
    
          }
    
        });
        // to be run when a row is deleted...this assigns ids to input elements in serial manner            
        var table = document.getElementById("mytab1");
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        
        // i has been initiated with 1, as header row is the 0th row
        for (var i = 1; i < rowCount; i++) {
          var row = table.rows[i];
    
          // on this line, getting error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`
          row.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].childNodes[0].childNodes[0].id = "social_rec" + i;
          row.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].childNodes[0].childNodes[1].for = "social_rec" + i;
          row.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].childNodes[0].childNodes[1].innerHTML = " " + i;
    
          row.childNodes[1].childNodes[0].childNodes[0].for = "name_social" + i;
          row.childNodes[1].childNodes[0].childNodes[1].list = "name_social" + i;
          row.childNodes[1].childNodes[0].childNodes[2].id = "name_social" + i;
    
          row.childNodes[2].childNodes[0].childNodes[0].id = "url_social" + i;
    
          //iterate through rows
          //rows would be accessed using the "row" variable assigned in the for loop
    
        }
    
      });
    
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered" id="mytab1">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">
            #
          </th>
          <th scope="col">
            Name
          </th>
          <th scope="col">
            URL
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="form-check">
                <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="social_rec1" name="social_rec">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="social_rec1"> 1</label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </th>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group shadow-sm">
              <label for="name_social1">Select or Type</label>
              <input type="text" list="name_social1" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
              <datalist id="name_social1">
                <option value="Wikipedia">Wikipedia</option>
                <option value="Youtube">Youtube</option>
                <option value="Facebook">Facebook</option>
                <option value="Twitter">Twitter</option>
                <option value="Pinterest">Pinterest</option>
              </datalist>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group shadow-sm">
              <textarea class="form-control" id="url_social1" cols="30" rows="1" placeholder="URL"></textarea>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="social_add_rec">Add Row</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="social_delete_rec">Delete Row</button>
```

## P.S. :

1. I have used jQuery and Bootstrap.
2. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41966001/javascript-type-error-childnodes-undefined) question seemed close, but I think I don't have the same mistake.

### Edit:

I need to display(or store) inputs by user, for which I wrote following JavaScript code.

```
var social = function () {

    var val = "social:\n";
    for (x = 1; x <= social_recs_num; x++) {
      //where social_recs_num is number of rows
      val = val + "\s\s-\n";
      val = val + "\s\s\s\s" + "name: " + getElementById("name_social" + x) + "\n";
      val = val + "\s\s\s\s" + "url: " + getElementById("url_social" + x) + "\n";
    }

    return val;

}
```

function `social` returns the value input by user in YAML format. For this code, when selected rows are deleted, I want to assign `id` to input elements and checkboxes of every remaining row in serial manner.

Comment: In my opinion it's much easier to serialize/index them when you're going to submit/save them vs dynamically in the interface assuming you don't need that index for some reason before then.

Comment: *I want to assign id to input elements and checkboxes of every remaining row in serial manner, so that the rows are always serially sound.* That is not really true and will cause a very brittle solution that requires a lot of maintenance and won't scale well. You can always identify elements by other means than id's.

Comment: There are much cleaner ways to target nested elements than chaining `childNodes[0].childNodes[0].childNodes[0]...`. Just reading that makes it impossible to know what is at the end. Mixing native methods and jQuery ones is not a good practice either. Use one or the other and be consistent

Comment: @NathanChampion Thanks. I actually need serially assigned id for another function. I have edited the question accordingly, with further explanations.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I am pretty new to JS. Should I be aware of some better alternatives to identify elements than by ids(maybe for cases like this one)? Code in the question is one that I came up with after some googling and efforts, though I would love to know if there is a more scalable alternative. Also I have further clarified the question.

Comment: Folks that are new to web development always gravitate to `id`s first because they are easy to understand and work with (at a simplistic level). The problem with them is that they have to be unique and so you wind up with scenarios like yours when new items are added or deleted - ids have to be managed. Also, `id`s are difficult to override in CSS for styling. Instead use classes and the HTML element structure as your way of finding elements within a document.

Comment: I see. That explains why answer to question is using classes and element tags for finding elements. Thanks @ScottMarcus .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The Problem:**

The issues you are seeing is because you are trying to get the 'childNodes' property of an html element. In order to access that property, you would have to cast the element as a jQuery object by adding '$( )' around it. In this case, that would be '$(row)'.

However, if you do that with your code, you still get errors because of the mess of nested .childNodes[0]. You could get it working using that existing code, however...

**Suggested Refactoring:**

...As other stated, there are more elegant ways to approach this problem. There are a number of ways you could tackle it, but given your current html I would refactor to something like this:

```
//...


// to be run when a row is deleted...this assigns ids to input elements in serial manner                
$('#mytab1 tbody tr').each(function() {
    var rowNum = $(this)[0].rowIndex;

    var formcheck = $(this).find('.form-check');  
    formcheck.find('.form-check-input')[0].id = 'social_rec' + rowNum;
    formcheck.find('.form-check-label')[0].for = 'social_rec' + rowNum;
    formcheck.find('.form-check-label')[0].innerHTML = ' ' + rowNum;

    var formName = $(this).find('td')[0];
    $(formName).find('label')[0].for = 'social_rec' + rowNum;
    $(formName).find('input')[0].list = 'social_rec' + rowNum;
    $(formName).find('datalist')[0].id = 'social_rec' + rowNum;

    var formUrl = $(this).find('td')[1];
    $(formUrl).find('textarea')[0].id = 'social_rec' + rowNum;          
});


//...
```

This replaces your for loop with a jquery .each loop and then uses the .find() function to loop up each control you want to manipulate. You'll also note that it is using the rowIndex() function to determine what number to assign the row.

I think the advantage to using an approach like this is that it's much easier to read the code and determine what controls are being affected. You could also additionally refactor your html to use classes that are unique to the controls you want to target, then you could just use the class selector to change those controls.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks. That helps a lot.

Comment: Though the code isn't giving errors, it seems that it isn't running as it should. After adding say 4 rows, if we delete the 3rd row, `datalist` tag becomes ineffective for the 3rd row among the remaining 3 rows. Seems that code is unable to change `for` and `list` attribute of `label` and `input` tags respectively. Side note: in case of `formName` and `formUrl`, `name_social` and `url_social`, respectively, should replace `social_rec` in the code. Here is a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jXqvaz).